# Phonegap / Cordova : how to build with ant in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: android, cordova, ant

I'm trying out Phonegap using both the command line and with Intellij IDEA.

When I create a new 'hello world'-project with

`phonegap create . com.example.test Test`

a folder `www` is created with all html-files. I'm told this is the place where you should do the changes to the source code.

But when I do '`phonegap local build android`' the contents of this folder is *copied* to 'platforms/android/assets/www'. I assume this is done by `ant`.

Now I want to use *only* Intellij IDEA for the building instead of the command line. I already managed to import the project into IDEA and run it, but only AFTER I did a local build using the command line first, so I assume IDEA found the copied 'assets/www' files to do the building/running.

Somehow it must be possible with Intellij IDEA to edit the normal `www` in the root but then when running, do exactly the same as `phonegap local build` does, but I can't figure out how.